# Display multiple values of a column in one row in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, crosstab

I have a query like this:

```
select to_date(to_char(registime, 'YYYY-MM'),'YYYY-MM') as dt,count(id) as total_call  
from all_info 
where alarm_id is null
group by dt   
order by dt
```

And the result just like this:

```
dt          total_call      
2011-03-01     45
2011-04-01     61
2011-05-01     62
2011-06-01     41
2011-07-01     48
2011-08-01     42
2011-09-01     28
2011-10-01     39
```

I want the result like in the demo below, a table form:

```
2011-03-01   2011-04-01  2011-05-01  2011-06-01  ..........
   45            61          62          41
```

I want to use **crosstab**, but it doesn't seem to work?

Comment: Sorry but how are you trying to display the data, what language/program are you using?

Comment: thanks Daniel, I just use the result as a datasource , in that case I can show the results in ireprot. Ireport is a report designer.

Comment: Is this any help: http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/14-CrossTab-Queries-in-PostgreSQL-using-tablefunc-contrib.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look into the contrib module **tablefunc**. It provides exactly the kind of pivot table functionality you are looking for.
See the [manual here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/tablefunc.html).

Follow the [installation instructions here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/contrib.html) or in the article @Paul Tomblin suggested in his comment above.

Then your function could look like this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM crosstab($$
SELECT 'total_calls'::text AS col_name
      ,to_char(registime, '"x"YYYY_MM_01') as dt
      ,count(id) as total_call  
FROM   all_info 
WHERE  alarm_id is null
GROUP  BY dt   
ORDER  BY dt
$$)
AS ct(
 call_day text
,x2011_03_01 int8
,x2011_04_01 int8
,x2011_05_01 int8
,x2011_06_01 int8
,x2011_07_01 int8
,x2011_08_01 int8
,x2011_09_01 int8
,x2011_10_01 int8);
```

Output:

```
  call_day   | x2011_03_01 | x2011_04_01 | x2011_05_01 | x2011_06_01 | x2011_07_01 | x2011_08_01 | x2011_09_01 | x2011_10_01
-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------
 total_calls |           1 |           4 |           4 |           2 |           1 |           5 |           1 |           1
```

Column names can't start with a digit (or you have to double-quote), that's why I prefixed the date with x. I also simplified your query.
You could wrap this in a view or function for repeated use.
Maybe a plpgsql function that dynamically adjusts the column names and EXECUTEs.

[More details, explanation and links in this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11751905/939860).

Comment: thanks man, very good. how can I accept your answer? I can't find it .

Comment: There is a  time limit of 15 minutes after the question being asked before you can accept an answer. See here for more info: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38090/discourage-questions-being-marked-as-answered-within-an-hour-or-so-of-being-post/44099#44099. And here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work. By now, if you refresh the page, you should see the check mark beside the answer.